# Regex for text file

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file with the following text:

```
 andal-4.1.0.jar
 besc_2.1.0-beta
 prov-3.0.jar
 add4lib-1.0.jar
 com_lab_2.0.jar
 astrix
 lis-2_0_1.jar
```

Is there any way i can split the name and the version using regex. I want to use the results to make two columns 'Name' and 'Version' in excel.
So i want the results from regex to look like

```
andal          4.1.0.jar
besc           2.1.0-beta
prov           3.0.jar
add4lib        1.0.jar
com_lab        2.0.jar
astrix
lis            2_0_1.jar
```

So far I have used `^(?:.*-(?=\d)|\D+)` to get the Version and `-\d.*$` to get the Name separately. The problem with this is that when i do it for a large text file, the results from the two regex are not in the same order. So is there any way to get the results in the way I have mentioned above?

Comment: Try `^(.*)[_-](\d.*)` => `$1\t$2`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew won't work

Comment: `^(.*?)[_-](\d+[._]\d.*)`? You should provide specs that would list all possible delimiters for the version numbers at least. Please provide the pattern requirements.

Comment: okay, you changed the requirement again...

Comment: @AdrianShum added lis-2_0_1.jar to the pattern requirnment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+?)[-_](\d.*)$`
- Replace with: `$1\t$2`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    (.+?)   # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    [-_]    # a dash or underscore
    (\d.*)  # group 2, a digit then 0 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
\t          # a tabulation, you may replace with what you want
$2          # content of group 2
```

**Result for given example:**

```
 andal  4.1.0.jar
 besc   2.1.0-beta
 prov   3.0.jar
 add4lib    1.0.jar
 com_lab    2.0.jar
 astrix
 lis    2_0_1.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you meant for the problem in large file, and I believe the two regex you showed are doing opposite as what you said: first one should get you the name and second one should give you version.

Anyway, here is the assumption I have to guess what may make sense to you:

- "Name" may follow by `-` or `_`, followed by version string.
- "Version" string is something preceded by `-` or `_`, with some digit, followed by a dot or underscore, followed by some digit, and then any string.

If these assumption make sense, you may use

```
^(.+?)(?:[-_](\d+[._]\d+.*))?$
```

as your regex.  Group 1 is will be the name, Group 2 will be the Version.

Demo in regex101:  https://regex101.com/r/RnwMaw/3

Explanation of regex

```
^                                   start of line
 (.+?)                              "Name" part, using reluctant match of 
                                      at least 1 character
      (?:                   )?   Optional group of "Version String", which
                                      consists of:
         [-_]                       - or _
             (             )         Followed by the "Version" , which is 
              \d+                      at least 1 digit, 
                 [._]                  then 1 dot or underscore, 
                     \d+               then at least 1 digit,
                        .*             then any string
                              $   end of line
```

Comment: this seems to removing all the lines in the text file.

Comment: Removing all lines? what do you meant by that?  As I said in the answer, you need to get the value from the 2 capture groups.  Have you checked the regex101 demo?

Comment: `(?:[-_](\d+[._]\d+.*))?` is working perfectly. However together the result is not as expected.